# How to execute multiple functions with many different twitter users without duplicating code?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making a wep app using the Twitter API 1.1 and have successfully created functions that pull-in a specified users profile image, their actual name and their latest tweet. All using OAuth to authenticate the requests.

My question is this - All 3 functions created expect a twitter user name to be defined. At the moment I have to duplicate my code over and over for each twitter user name I put in. Surely there is a better way of doing it? As at the moment my code doesn't look good at all. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. I'm pretty new to PHP so am stuck on what to do.

Please see my code below: 
    The functions:

```
function getTweets($user, $tmhOAuth){
$usertweets = array();

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/user_timeline'), array(
  'include_entities'    => '1',
  'include_rts'         => '1',
  'screen_name'         => $user,
  'count'               => 1,
  'exclude_replies'     => 'true',
  'contributor_details' => 'true'
));


if ($code == 200) {
  $timeline = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true); 
  foreach ($timeline as $tweet) :
    $entified_tweet = tmhUtilities::entify_with_options($tweet);
    $is_retweet = isset($tweet['retweeted_status']);

    $diff = time() - strtotime($tweet['created_at']);
    if ($diff < 60*60)
      $created_at = floor($diff/60) . ' minutes ago';
    elseif ($diff < 60*60*24)
      $created_at = floor($diff/(60*60)) . ' hours ago';
    else
      $created_at = date('d M', strtotime($tweet['created_at']));

    $permalink  = str_replace(
      array(
        '%screen_name%',
        '%id%',
        '%created_at%'
      ),
      array(
        $tweet['user']['screen_name'],
        $tweet['id_str'],
        $created_at,
      ),
      '<a href="https://twitter.com/%screen_name%/%id%">%created_at%</a>'
    );
     $tweet['created_at'] = $created_at;
     $usertweets[] = $tweet;
   endforeach;
   } else {
       tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response);
}
    return $usertweets;
}

function getImage($screen_name,$tmhOAuth,$size = ''){
$url = $tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/users/show'), array(
  'screen_name' => $screen_name,
));

$results = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);

//Get the user's profile image
$profileImg = ($results['profile_image_url']);
return str_replace('_normal', $size, $profileImg);
}

function getName($screen_name,$tmhOAuth){
$url = $tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/users/show'), array(
  'screen_name' => $screen_name,
));

$results = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true);

//Get the user's name
$name = ($results['name']);
return $name;
}
```

How the functions are implemented:

```
$name2 = getName("JoeyEssex_",$tmhOAuth);
$user2 = getTweets("JoeyEssex_",$tmhOAuth);
$image2 = getImage("JoeyEssex_",$tmhOAuth);

$name3 = getName("piersmorgan",$tmhOAuth);
$user3 = getTweets("piersmorgan",$tmhOAuth);
$image3 = getImage("piersmorgan",$tmhOAuth);

$name4 = getName("BinkyFelstead",$tmhOAuth);
$user4 = getTweets("BinkyFelstead",$tmhOAuth);
$image4 = getImage("BinkyFelstead",$tmhOAuth);

//Display the profile images of specified users

echo '<img src="' . $image2 . '" width="240px" height="240px" />';
echo '<img src="' . $image3 . '" width="240px" height="240px" />';
echo '<img src="' . $image4 . '" width="240px" height="240px" />';

//Display user's name
echo '<p>Latest tweet from <b>' . $name1 . '</b>:<br />';
//Display their tweets
foreach($user1 as $tweet){ 
echo $tweet['text'] . '<br />';
echo "Sent: <b>" . $tweet['created_at'] . "</b></p>";
}

echo '<b>' . $name2 . '</b>&nbsp;';
foreach($user2 as $tweet){
echo $tweet['text'];
echo "&nbsp;" . $tweet['created_at'] . "<br />";
}

echo '<b>' . $name3 . '</b>&nbsp;';
foreach($user3 as $tweet){
echo $tweet['text'];
echo "&nbsp;" . $tweet['created_at'] . "<br />";
}

echo '<b>' . $name4 . '</b>&nbsp;';
foreach($user4 as $tweet){
echo $tweet['text'];
echo "&nbsp;" . $tweet['created_at'] . "<br />";
}
```

You see the horrible repetition? There's got to be a better way!

Comment: And your question is? Why weren't you able to write it in a better way? Where did you hit the wall? Are you looking for arrays? http://php.net/array

Comment: @hakre I sure have hit the wall! Please could you provide me with an example of what you mean? Like I said I'm pretty new to PHP, so I'm not sure how arrays would help?

Comment: Arrays are a list/collection of variables, so instead of `$name1` to `$nameN` you have got `$name[0]` up to `$name[$n]`. So you can create an array of names and then run the function call in a loop. That is basic programming, merely independent to the programming language. Most programming languages have loops and also list/collections/arrays. http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Thank you so much for this @hakre . I could really do with an example with my code above used? I've clearly missed a vital gap in learning the correct methods of php, and without an example I just don't understand. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part that differs in the duplicated code is actually the name of the person tweeting. So create a list of all the tweeters names and iterate over it. Change the code inside the `foreach` loop to reflect the new input and processing:

```
$tweeters = array('JoeyEssex_', 'piersmorgan', 'BinkyFelstead');

foreach ($tweeters as $tweeter)
{
    $tweeter_name   = getName($tweeter, $tmhOAuth);
    $tweeter_tweets = getTweets($tweeter, $tmhOAuth);
    $tweeter_image  = getImage($tweeter, $tmhOAuth);    

    // Display the profile images of user
    echo '<img src="' . $tweeter_image . '" width="240px" height="240px" />';

    // Display user's name
    echo '<p>Latest tweet from <b>' . tweeter_name . '</b>:<br />';

    // Display user's tweets
    foreach ($tweeter_tweets as $tweet)
    {
        echo $tweet['text'] . '<br />';
        echo "Sent: <b>" . $tweet['created_at'] . "</b></p>";
    }
}
```

Putting the repetition into a loop is a common way to express code-duplication in the meaning to do the same over and over again.

Additionally you can even start to wrap the functionality into a `Tweeter` class:

```
class Tweeter {

    private $name;
    private $tmhOAuth;

    public function __construct($name, $tmhOAuth) {
        $this->name     = $name;
        $this->tmhOAuth = $tmhOAuth;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return getName($this->name, $this->tmhOAuth);
    }

    public function getTweets() {
        return getTweets($this->name, $this->tmhOAuth);
    }

    public function getImage() {
        return getImage($this->name, $this->tmhOAuth);
    }
}
```

This is quickly written, naturally you can even move the code from the existing `get...` functions *into* the class methods, but I kept it step-by-step doing a quick first change without removing existing code.

The usage then is fairly straight forward:

```
$tweeters = array('JoeyEssex_', 'piersmorgan', 'BinkyFelstead');

// Create all Tweeter objects
foreach ($tweeters as $i => $tweeter)
{
    $tweeters[$i] = new Tweeter($tweeter, $tmhOAuth);
}

// Display all Tweeters

foreach ($tweeters as $tweeter)
{
    echo '<img src="' . $tweeter->getImage() . '" width="240px" height="240px" />';

    echo '<p>Latest tweet from <b>' . $tweeter->getName() . '</b>:<br />';

    foreach ($tweeter->getTweets() as $tweet)
    {
        echo $tweet['text'] . '<br />';
        echo "Sent: <b>" . $tweet['created_at'] . "</b></p>";
    }
}
```

This will enable you to start profiting from object oriented programming.

Comment: That makes loads more sense! I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on. Thank you for helping me see the light!

Comment: Hakre, thank you so much for this! I've managed to implement it successfully and I've moved the previous functions into the class methods and it works perfectly. With the code that cycles through the functions with each tweeter using the 'foreach' loop, how would I make it so when the tweeters profile image is clicked, their tweet appears in a lightbox? I'm able to create the lightbox and everything myself using jQuery, but how do I make it so each tweeters profile image is assigned to their unique tweet? Using the code you've provided above. Sorry for all the questions, you're a great help!

Comment: I've just given it a go and all tweets are appearing in the lightbox, not each individual tweet dependant on the profile image clicked. Any help to my comment above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need 100% the same output order as in the question (first all the images) and then all the tweets per each user? If so, then do two foreachs with the `Tweeter` objects. First display all images and in the second `foreach` display the tweets. I'm not 100% sure I understood you correctly, so hopefully this is still of help ;)

Comment: Hi Hakre, the order really doesn't matter. What I'm trying to achieve is an application where the user can add twitter accounts, (in this case the accounts in the array - piers morgan etc) and then the app displays all the profile images of the added accounts. Each profile image can then be clicked, displaying their latest tweet. For example - I add Piers Morgan to the app, and then his profile image is pulled in from Twitter. When I click on his profile image I can then see what he has tweeted. I would like this functionality to be available for any account added to the array. Does this help?

Comment: Yes it helps me to understand what you want to do, but I now see this is a different question. Try to read a bit about jQuery now, there are a lot of examples, read about those you smell that might be fitting. At the end of the day, you will know which javascript code is required and what HTML is needed. In PHP you then generate the needed HTML with the loops as outlined in the answer. You can create a HTML + JS mock first and add the PHP part later (or do a mock even with PHP, depends on how much you want to do at once).

Comment: Both the HTML and javascript is in place and ready to go, my problem is the PHP. I'm just stuggling to know how to get just the tweet of a single account in the array when their profile image is clicked. As my knowledge in using the foreach loop isn't very good, I just get all the tweets from every account in the array showing up. I'm using your code above, but now I'm stuck. Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Well the code above is likely not fitting for that part of the problem. You need to arrange the output in a different order to obtain the format you need. Just influence the execution of the script so that the desired output comes out. I bet it's not that complicated as it looks to you right now. Play around with it, try out something different, just for fun and it will probably just make "click".

Comment: And keep in mind that not only in PHP there are loops, but in javascript and jquery, they are forms of loops, too.

Comment: @Tom: Well my flight is round the corner and I just have zero time regardless how much money you offer to pay (well reasonable ;) ).

Comment: I've solved the issue! You were right, I just needed to play around with it and influence the execution in a different way. Thank you for all your help.